# Update a file on S3 based on S3 trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm uploading a file to S3 and have a trigger on the S3 that runs a Lambda function to update the file. When I write the file back to S3 after the update will that trigger Lambda to run again causing an infinite loop of updates on the file?

The file is being put there by another Lambda function. If it causes an infinite loop I'll use SNS however this will be more complex for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing, would indeed cause an infinite loop.

I can see two options to avoid this.

The simplest would be to drop the amended file into a separate bucket (or a separate folder if you set your S3 trigger to a different folder).

Another option would be to invoke the lambda that updates your file from the lambda that drops the file into S3. You could use a middleman here, e.g. first lambda sends something to SNS/SQS, which in turn triggers the lambda that updates the file.

Comment: Think I'll go the lambda function calling SNS on needed files. Cheers.